# Luggage storage options at Heathrow airport?

Tags: luggage, lhr, luggage-storage

In case the airline will not store my luggage for a 15 hour layover, is there a place in the LHR airport or in Admirals Club to store it?

Answer (score 5):

If you're asking whether they have left luggage facilities, they do, as the [**Heathrow website**](http://www.heathrow.com/airport-guide/terminal-facilities-and-services/left-baggage) mentions:

> There are left luggage/baggage storage facilities in each terminal at
>   Heathrow airport. Baggage and luggage items can be stored for a few
>   hours or up to 90 days.

Find prices, locations, and other details on that webpage. (It was the [first Google hit](https://www.google.com/search?q=lhr%20luggage%20storage) by the way.)

If your luggage is checked through to TLV, then you of course do not need to worry about it.

Answer (score 4):

To expand Jonik's answer, here are the [current prices](http://www.heathrow.com/airport-guide/terminal-facilities-and-services/left-baggage) for luggage storage at Heathrow:

[image]

And here are the opening hours at each terminal:

[image]